# Import a subpackage with an unknown number of modules

Tags: python, import

I'm building a package that is a wrapper for an API. I want this wrapper to be as accomodating as possible towards future versions of this API. For these reason, I have a generic `wrapper.py` that defines a generic wrapper class and has the user choose the version of the API that they want to use.

The API methods are defined in a different file in the `versions` subdirectory for each version of the API. There are a theoretically infinite number of versions - I want this to be as future-proof as possible.

```
.
└── MyApiWrapper
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── versions
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── v1.py
    │   ├── v2.py
    │   ├── v3.py
    │   └── ...
    └── wrapper.py
```

The contents of both `__init__.py` are empty. Each API version `v1.py`, `v2.py`, ... , `vN.py` defines a single `Api` class.

My problem is importing the different versions of the API in `wrapper.py`. Because I'm not able to specify each filename individually, I'm looking to import `versions` and then work from there.

The end goal is that I should be able to add a new API version by adding the respective module to `versions` without having to make any changes to `wrapper.py`.

I've tried the following different versions of `wrapper.py`. Note that the intent is to avoid manually specifying `v1`, `v2`, etc. However, I'm getting the value of `versions.v1` here just as a quick test of the import.

```py
>>> import MyApiWrapper
>>> print(MyApiWrapper.versions.v1.Api)
AttributeError: module 'MyApiWrapper' has no attribute 'versions'
```

```py
>>> from MyApiWrapper import versions
>>> print(versions.v1.Api)
AttributeError: module 'MyApiWrapper.versions' has no attribute 'v1'
```

```py
>>> import MyApiWrapper.versions
>>> print(MyApiWrapper.versions.v1.Api)
AttributeError: module 'MyApiWrapper.versions' has no attribute 'v1'
```

```py
>>> import MyApiWrapper
>>> from MyApiWrapper.versions import *
>>> print(MyApiWrapper.versions.v1.Api)
AttributeError: module 'MyApiWrapper.versions' has no attribute 'v1'
```

Obviously the following works, but it's not future-proof:

```py
>>> import MyApiWrapper
>>> from MyApiWrapper.versions import v1
>>> print(MyApiWrapper.versions.v1.Api)
<class 'MyApiWrapper.versions.v1.Api'>
```

This also works, but it's not ideal as I'd have to generate the module names one by one:

```py
>>> import importlib
>>> import MyApiWrapper
>>> importlib.import_module('.v1', 'MyApiWrapper.versions')
>>> print(MyApiWrapper.versions.v1.Api)
<class 'MyApiWrapper.versions.v1.Api'>
```

How can I import all modules from the `versions` subpackage without specifying their names?

Answer (score 0):

The contents of an imported package are, essentially, the global variables of its `__init__.py`. (There's also `__all__`, if you'd like to include only some of these globals, but the key point remains). I assume your `version/__init__.py` is empty, so when you import `versions`, it has no members. The simple solution would be to add the following contents to it:

```
from . import v1, v2, v3, ...
```

That does require manual listing of subelements, but it is al least localized within the subpackage. If you'd like to automate it further, you could go with something like:

```
import pathlib
import importlib

__all__ = []

for path in pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.glob("v*.py"):
    importlib.import_module(f".{path.stem}", __package__)
    __all__.append(path.stem)
```

This way all files matching the `v*.py` pattern will be available as members of the imported version module.

In both cases, you'll be able to use any form of importing you've specified in your question without a problem.